# jQuery - Bottom Yellow bar of Main Navigation looses focus while you hover over their subnavigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Example:** http://jtstratford.advisorproducts.com/about

Bottom Yellow bar of Main Navigation looses focus while you hover over their Sub Navigation, - So it will remain on their Main navigation when you hover over their Sub Navigation.

**Below is the JS code:**

```
// DOM Ready
$(function () {

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth;

    /* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */
    $("#magicLine").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

    /* Cache it */
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".selectednav").width())
        .css("left", $(".selectednav a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#magicLine > li").children("a").hover(function () {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function () {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do a hover function on list element and not on children anchor.

```
 $("#magicLine > li").hover(function...
```

This way your mouseout effect will not be triggered while you're in same list element.

Comment: While doing this yellow line takes full width of UL

Comment: No problem. You changed (recalculated it) with of yellow line right?

Comment: $("#magicLine > li").hover(function ()

and 

newWidth = $el.width();

No i removed children() from above line and parent() form bottom so now it takes exact with of li and previously it was taking ul witdh.